# Proving $\mathcal P(A-B) = \mathcal P (A) -\mathcal P (B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I started with trying to prove $\mathcal P(A-B) \subseteq \mathcal P (A) - \mathcal P (B)$

$x \in \mathcal P (A) - \mathcal P (B)$ that mean

$x \in \mathcal P (A)  \wedge x \notin \mathcal P (B)$ means

$x \in A \wedge x \notin B$ meaning

$x \in A-B$ therefore $x \in \mathcal P (A) - \mathcal P (B)$

And using the same arguments for $\mathcal P (A) - \mathcal P (B) \subseteq \mathcal P(A-B)  $

Am I on the right way?

Thanks

Comment: A note to the title: assume that $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $B=\{4,5\}$.  What can you say about the set $x=\{1, 5\}$?

Comment: What is meant by $\wp\left(A\right)$? If it denotes the powerset (i.e.
set of subsets of $A$) then $x\in\wp\left(A\right)$ means $x\subset S$
and then it is not true that $\wp\left(A-B\right)=\wp\left(A\right)-\wp\left(B\right)$

Comment: Is $\emptyset$ an element of $\mathcal P(A-B)$? Is it an element of $\mathcal P(A)-\mathcal P(B)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid your reasoning has gone awry. $x\in\mathcal P(A)\wedge x\notin\mathcal P(B)$ means that $x\subseteq A\wedge x\nsubseteq B$. From this, though, we cannot conclude that $x\subseteq A\setminus B$--to do that, we would need to know that $x$ and $B$ were disjoint--so we can't conclude that $x\in\mathcal P(A\setminus B)$.

Moreover, you're working in the wrong direction to show that $\mathcal P(A\setminus B)\subseteq\mathcal P(A)\setminus\mathcal P(B).$ You'd need to start with an element of $\mathcal P(A\setminus B).$

However, *regardless* of $A$ and $B$, we will *always* have $\mathcal P(A\setminus B)\nsubseteq\mathcal P(A)\setminus\mathcal P(B),$ since $\emptyset\in\mathcal P(A\setminus B),$ but $\emptyset\notin\mathcal P(A)\setminus\mathcal P(B).$

Moreover, it is *rarely* the case that $\mathcal P(A\setminus B)\supseteq\mathcal P(A)\setminus\mathcal P(B).$ Consider $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{1,2\},$ for example. In general, if $A$ has more than two elements, then for any $B\not\supseteq A,$ we have that $\mathcal P(A)\setminus\mathcal P(B)$ has strictly more elements than $\mathcal P(A\setminus B),$ and so the latter cannot be a superset of the former.